# Showing closest matches from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble with getting this to work.

Excuse my english.

Here's what im trying to achieve: When you enter a set of measurements e.g length 300mm height 400mm width 55mm i want the closest matches to those measurements e.g top 3? So if another product has these measurements length 310mm height 410mm width 60mm i want the program to show this product because its close to the original measurements. My database has over 300 different products with different  measurements. i want the program to show you the product name and product measurements.

Sorry if this is too vague.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty vague. Can you give better examples of input and output with respect to their specific expression (array? string? XML?) and what you've done to **try and solve it**?

Comment: "I'm having trouble with getting this to work." Maybe that wasn't the right wording, what i meant to say was that i have an idea of what to do but no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a coding but a mathematical issue because it fully depends on how to define 'close'.

A very easy example could be to simply:

1. Add up length, height and width of the original, do the same for each product, and show the product which has the smallest difference of the total.
2. Or you could only show it if the difference in total is not higher than 10% of the original total.
3. Or you could to the same technique as above but for each property: Show products (or the first product) where the difference per length, heigth and width are lower than 10% of the original property.
4. And there are very complex mathematical models out there which try to 'get close' or to 'minimize difference'.

Without providing further details you won't get an answer here.

And please don't ask mathematical but programming questions only anyway.

Comment: Well maybe it is a mathematical issue but i'm also looking for help on how to actually execute this. I'm quite the novice.

Comment: "execute THIS" - this is exactly the issue - nobody here can guess what "THIS" is. Carl Jan's answer gives you some impression on how to adress this technically. Best luck - and feel free to ask a new question anytime if you have some idea what you want to achieve and share your issues on the way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to LBA's answer, your best approach is either by volume difference, or l/w/h difference. If you're looking to get the closest matches, you need to use ordering instead of conditions. If you don't care about the shapes being different, then work out the volume (whl) and create a sort by difference in volume. If you care about shape, then you'll need to do this for width, height and length separately ... though you should still use some form of condition so that if the closest matches are far from the subject dimensions then you don't get any results ... good luck

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `column_length` <= length_var AND `column_width` <= width_var AND `column_height` <= height_var
ORDER BY `product_id` ASC
LIMIT 3
```

This only shows the top 3 from your chosen measurements and below. And I'm not sure if there is an error in the syntax, but you get the flow

Comment: LBA's answer is the closest you can get. And since you have quite a number of rows, computing the total for each will be a little time-consuming, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm going to try this, thanks.

Comment: Ordering by product id is doing nothing toward what the OP wants, not to mention you are only finding products smaller than the entry

Comment: He can use any column instead of product_id, I just used it because it's common in many database, and my purpose is just to sort the result. Yeah, it will give me 3 results starting from the given data below, although it is not  the answer to the OP's problem, it can be an alternative if he didn't manage to code LBA's answer